# Swift JavaScriptCore crash sometimes (bmalloc::VMHeap::grow())

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use javaScriptCore in my swift project, there has two images on the webview, I want click the image to present my swift viewController, in html, the function of click image named "scanImgs", this is my code

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    guard let context = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as? JSContext else {
        return
    }

    let scanImgs: @convention(block) (String, String, Int) -> Void = { (image1: String, image2: String, index: Int) in

        let photosVC: UIViewController = SpursPhotoBrowserViewController.getPhotoBrowser(image1, secondImageURL: image2, selectIndex: UInt(index))

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            self.presentViewController(photosVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(scanImgs, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "scanImgs")

}
```

this code can running right most of time, but sometimes i get crash in JavaScriptCore, this is crash log

```
 0 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() + 132
 1 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() + 56
 2 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallPage(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long) + 244
 3 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::Heap::refillSmallBumpRangeCache(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, bmalloc::FixedVector<bmalloc::BumpRange, 32ul>&) + 36
 4 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::Allocator::allocateBumpRangeSlowCase(unsigned long) + 128
 5 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::Allocator::allocateSlowCase(unsigned long) + 180
 6 WebCore  cssyyparse(WebCore::CSSParser*) + 1232
 7 WebCore  WebCore::CSSParser::parseSheet(WebCore::StyleSheetContents*, WTF::String const&, WTF::TextPosition const&, WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::CSSRuleSourceData>, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>*, bool) + 488
 8 WebCore  WebCore::StyleSheetContents::parseAuthorStyleSheet(WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet const*, WebCore::SecurityOrigin const*) + 164
 9 WebCore  WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::setCSSStyleSheet(WTF::String const&, WebCore::URL const&, WTF::String const&, WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet const*) + 996
 10 WebCore WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet::didAddClient(WebCore::CachedResourceClient*) + 116
 11 WebCore WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::process() + 2064
 12 WebCore WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::insertedInto(WebCore::ContainerNode&) + 80
 13 WebCore WebCore::ChildNodeInsertionNotifier::notify(WebCore::Node&, WTF::Vector<WTF::Ref<WebCore::Node>, 11ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&) + 164
 14 WebCore WebCore::ContainerNode::notifyChildInserted(WebCore::Node&, WebCore::ContainerNode::ChildChangeSource) + 172
 15 WebCore WebCore::ContainerNode::parserAppendChild(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Node>) + 240
 16 WebCore WebCore::insert(WebCore::HTMLConstructionSiteTask&) + 228
 17 WebCore WebCore::HTMLConstructionSite::executeQueuedTasks() + 148
 18 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::constructTreeFromHTMLToken(WebCore::HTMLTokenizer::TokenPtr&) + 156
 19 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode) + 352
 20 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::append(WTF::PassRefPtr<WTF::StringImpl>) + 608
 21 WebCore WebCore::DecodedDataDocumentParser::appendBytes(WebCore::DocumentWriter&, char const*, unsigned long) + 116
 22 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitData(char const*, unsigned long) + 596
 23 WebKitLegacy    -[WebHTMLRepresentation receivedData:withDataSource:] + 112
 24 WebKitLegacy    -[WebDataSource(WebInternal) _receivedData:] + 68
 25 WebKitLegacy    WebFrameLoaderClient::committedLoad(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, char const*, int) + 112
 26 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 172
 27 WebCore WebCore::CachedRawResource::didAddClient(WebCore::CachedResourceClient*) + 828
 28 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 148
 29 WebCore WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 36
 30 CoreFoundation  ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
 31 CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
 32 CoreFoundation  ___CFRunLoopRun + 1520
 33 CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
 34 WebCore RunWebThread(void*) + 456
 35 libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_body + 156
 36 libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_body
```

what's wrong with this bug...

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same issue recently, it may be a webkit's [bug](https://opensource.apple.com/source/bmalloc/bmalloc-7602.4.8/ChangeLog)
You could try `[webview stopLoading]` when viewWillDisappear. It would be helpful to fix this crash

Answer (score 0):

@David Hu
You could try [webview stopLoading] when viewWillDisappear. It would be helpful to fix this crash
Bug if [webview stopLoading], have other problems occur